# Microsoft VBscript runtime error: Object required: '[string: """new 1.cmd"""]' . Not sure that exactly is causing this to happen

Tags: vbscript

Here is my code:

```
Dim strContents, objRegx, mkey, objShell, objUser, objFile
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objRegx = New RegExp
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objString = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set objUser = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
Set objPath = objFSO.BuildPath(CurrentDirectory, """new 1.cmd""")

objRegx.Pattern = "\[(.*?)\]"
objRegx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegx.Global = True

WScript.Echo "Acquiring data ..."
objShell.Run objPath, 1, True

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\windows\temp\plik1.txt")

strContents = objFile.ReadAll

mkey = objRegx.Replace(strContents, "")

WScript.Echo mkey

objFile.Close
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error when running the script.

Comment: I'd say the error is `Set objPath = objFSo.BuildPath(CurrentDirectory, """new 1.cmd""")` what's the escaped quotes meant to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Set objPath = objFSO.BuildPath(CurrentDirectory, """new 1.cmd""")
> ```

You have 3 mistakes in that statement:

- The nested double quotes in `"""new 1.cmd"""` make them part of the actual filename, which is [not allowed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#naming_conventions). `FileSystemObject` methods can handle paths with spaces by themselves, without additional double quotes. You do need to add double quotes when passing the path to the [`Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky.aspx) method, though.
- [`CurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc5edzd.aspx) is a property of `WshShell` objects, not a builtin variable.
- The [`BuildPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt.aspx) method returns a string, not an object, so you need to remove the [`Set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44.aspx) keyword.

This will do what you want:

```
objPath = objFSO.BuildPath(objShell.CurrentDirectory, "new 1.cmd")
...
objShell.Run """" & objPath & """", 1, True
```

Comment: Now I seem to have gotten another runtime error. Object required: '[string: "C:\Users\wojte_000\D"]'

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Thank you so much for the clear and educational answer